# Вопрос проектировния счетчика в асинхронных методах

Tags: c#, .net

Многие из нас много раз сталкивались с потребностью подсчета какого либо значения в методе. И значение, которое подсчитывается, должно где то храниться (например в статическом поле класса). Для многопоточных алгоритмов это:

```
lock (syncObj)
Interlocked.Increment(ref int)
```

Но для асинхронных методов любое блокирование метода - очень нежелательно. Я пробовал обойтись очередью на основе `BlockingCollection` - но к сожалению методы срабатывают очень быстро и скорости передачи\получения коллекции не хватает.

Как именно можно выйти из положения?

Comment: Расскажите немного больше о _смысле_ этого самого счётчика.

Comment: @VladD, возьмем самый простой - сколько раз сработал метод. Либо сколько раз изменилось значение переменной в методе.

Comment: В этом случае я бы скорее всего вернул количество изменений переменной в методе как часть возвращаемого значения.

Comment: @VladD, в принципе понятно. Либо возвращать значение из метода (что тоже не совсем удобно\правильно), либо использовать все теже методы для многопоточной реализации.

Comment: Смотря по смыслу счётчика. Если это прогресс-индикатор, то через `IProgress`. Если это результат, то через возвращаемое значение. Побочных эффектов лучше избегать, особенно в многопоточном программировании.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просуммирую обсуждение в комментариях в ответ.

Если речь идёт об асинхронном коде, то имеет смысл не производить побочных эффектов. Например потому, что они требуют синхронизации.

Поэтому я бы порекомендовал попробовать другие подходы, в зависимости от *смысла* счётчика.

- Если счётчик нужен для накопления какой-либо информации, получающейся в результате пробега метода, стоит возвращать инкремент счётчика как часть возвращаемого значения. В конце-концов, это часть результата функции.
- Если счётчик нужен для сообщения о *процессе* пробега функции, стоит передавать в функцию `IProgress<T>`, и пусть функция сообщает о ходе выполнения через него. Стандартная реализация `Progress<T>` маршаллирует значения в UI-поток, и тем самым не должна тормозить ход вычислений.

Comment: Одно уточнение - стандартная реализация Progress<T> является потокобезопасной? Допустим несколько потоков отправляют репорты в Progress<int>(ReportProgress), в методе ReportProgress идет простой инкремент значений. Не будет ли потери точности? И второй вопрос - если есть синхронизация - то каково внутреннее устройство Progress<T>? что там используется (очередь, делегат и пр.)?

Comment: @Alexis: насколько я понимаю, `Progress<T>` просто вызывает переданный ему в конструкторе делегат, причём если `Progress<T>` создавать в UI-потоке, то делегат вызывается в том же UI-потоке, независимо от того, где произошёл вызов `Report`.

Comment: Так что потерь не будет, это ж просто вызов на диспетчере.